# Replace all characters between Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace an entire String with `""` (an empty string).

I have a string, like the one that follows:

```
<code code="34068-7"
```

However, the number at the end can be anything (in this example it is 7),
So, basically, I want to replace everything between `<` and the final number, including the `<` and the final number,  with `""`.  Since the number can be any digit, how can I do this with regex?

I have tried this:

```
 line = line.replaceAll("<code.*?\">","");
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please make some examples? Include some toy inputs like you already did, but also the expected and the current output. Then it will be clear. Because, at the moment, I do not get what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
line = line.replaceAll("<code code=\"[0-9-]+\"", "");
```

That pattern is only flexible about the data in the attribute value, the rest is assumed static.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what OP wants. I think he only wants to replace a specific part in the text, or maybe extract the number at the end. We will probably need for OP to clarify things (not my down-vote by the way).

Comment: @Zabuza The question says `I want to replace anything between < and number" and including the < and number"`. I understand that to mean replace the entire string with `""`. Can you perhaps share how you came to that understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("(?<=\\<)code.*?\"", "");
```

This lookbehind regexp will ensure that the `<` at the beginning of your string will not be replaced by "", so your example output will be

`<34068-7"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ernest_k's answer, you can also replace numbers in regex with \d for better readability. So the regex would be:

```
<code code=\"[\d-]+\"
```